# why am viewing only UIImage of last element in xml file from url in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

When i retrieve the XML file from URL, i can Parse all the elements from the XML file and view in log file, my parsing code looks like this,

```
-(id) loadXMLByURL:(NSString *)urlString{
tweets  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
parser.delegate = self;
[parser parse];
return self;}


-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Products"]){
currentTweet = [egsBase alloc];}}


-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"img"]){
currentTweet.img=[UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:currentNodeContent]]];}
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Products"]) {
[tweets addObject:currentTweet.img];
currentTweet = nil;
currentNodeContent = nil;}}


- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
 currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];}
```

I use the class name for parsing as `XmlParsing` . In the controller class i had implement the class file `XmlParsing` as `XmlParsing xmlparser;` Now in viewDidLoad() function i use code like this,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
xmlParser = [[XMLParsing alloc] loadXMLByURL:@"http://images.com/Products.xml"];
UIImage *currentImage = [[xmlParser tweets] objectAtIndex:0];
customimage.image = currentImage;}
```

Here the `customimage` is reference for UIImageView, Now the problem is i can get only the last element value and show in the UIImageView connected in story board (ie) for better understanding it shows only the last element image and not the previous elements i use in elements. how to solve this ? where am doing wrong. Kindly suggest me.

**STRUCTURE OF XML**

```
<Products>
 <products id="1">
   <img>http://images.com/images/Main_pic.png</img>
 </products>
 <products id="2">
  <img>http://images.com/images/image1.png</img>
 </products>
</Products>
```

My NSLog shows for parsing XML file,

```
images <UIImage: 0x71529a0>
images <UIImage: 0x74a6750>
```

When i print to check what image i get it shows the current image as,

```
Current,<UIImage: 0x74a6750>
```

here you can see the current image shows the last element alone not the previous one

Comment: at your didEndElement you need to crate mutable arraywith all image url and display what you wont and at your above code you just check if([elementName isEqualToString:@"img"]) so every image hase value for key is img and at last image url disply in your imageview

Comment: where are you initializing the `currentNodeContent` also each time you are replacing the content of that string not appending it. I'm sure it won't work. Also post the structure of your xml

Comment: i had added the xml file and the log output for your reference and the `currentNodeContent` is `NSMutableString *currentNodeContent;`

Comment: @nitin: you can see the mutable array as `tweets` that i added all the elements inside the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 1) [super viewDidLoad];
 2) xmlParser = [[XMLParsing alloc] loadXMLByURL:@"http://images.com/Products.xml"];
 3) UIImage currentImage = [[xmlParser tweets] objectAtIndex:0];
 4) customimage.image = currentImage;
}
```

I have added line numbers for ease of understanding :

**Line number 3** : You always get a new image (Am i right?)

**Line number 4** : whenever u get a new image you set that image to the same 
                imageview(customimage) due to this previous images gets replaced 
                with the new one.

Ideally you should set every new image to respective image views.

**If u r trying to load these images in a table view ---**
Then name of image view remains same but actually the object is different so you should access the imageview of each cell by its TAG assigned in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

**Updated Code**

```
-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict 
{
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"products"])
{
        currentTweet = [egsBase alloc];}}
}

-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
  if([elementName isEqualToString:@"img"])
   {
    currentTweet.img=[UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:currentNodeContent]]];
    [tweets addObject:currentTweet.img];
   }
 if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"products"])
  {
   currentTweet = nil;
   currentNodeContent = nil;
  }
}
```

Desc : while parsing when "products" is found as start element and object gets created, and when end element is found image gets associated to objects and gets added to array.
I see the error is : you are using "Products" in parsing condition instead of "products"

Hope the idea helps
:)

Comment: Thanks for ur response swati, 3) i always get the new image i added in xml. 4) No i didnt do so eg: if i have a logo image and a main image i refered the logo image in this line 4. but dont know to attach the main image in program if i add another line for the objectAtIndex:1 den it shows error. FYI am not using table view here just a logo and a main pic (Two UIImageView in story board) hope u understand this

Comment: [xmlParser tweets] : this must be an array, do check how many elements exists in this array.

Comment: ya its an array and i checked it as expected it shows all the images in NSLog output but how can i show it in UIImage that my prob, since as i mentioned the currentimage shows only last element not the previous one

Comment: it means array contains 2 objects each having image, in this case----UIImage *currentImage = [[xmlParser tweets] objectAtIndex:1]; should not show an exception, can u check what exactly the error is at this point??

Comment: No, when i use objectAtIndex:1 it terminates like this, *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Comment: this means that array contains only one object that can be accessed by index:0

Comment: u should check the parser method so that it should return array with 2 objects each containing an image

Comment: try this :  -(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"img"])
 {
 currentTweet.img=[UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:currentNodeContent]]];
    [tweets addObject:currentTweet.img];
 }
}

Comment: exactly swati, i tested NSLog in didEndElement of above code you see in that, [tweets addObject:currentTweet.img]; shows me only one element as you said [note: tweets is array here], but in the same log when i use NSLog for currentTweet.img it shows all images. Now what i wanna do

Comment: in my last comment : i have changed ur code a bit, the moment i get image i assign it to the image property of "currentTweet" object and save the "currentTweet" object in an array

Comment: fantastic swati, I like u lot got the output after 3 days of struggle Thank u so much can u give ur mail id if u wish i can query thro that if i need help in future

Comment: thank u, atleast your problem got solved, m always available on this site or u can tell me ur prob on my blog :)

Comment: k Thank u, one more doubt i have from the same xml i need some images to show in tableview how can use that both in program and story board i have idea to program as i see lots of tutorial for table view. but how can i place the multiple images in stoaryboard of  tableview thats confuse me

Comment: for that u need to create a tableViewCell that contains image view, use that tableViewCell to create a complete tableView, do not forget to set tags for image views when displayed in a tableView

Comment: do you have any links or tutorials for assigning tags for images in tableview if so kindly provide me

Comment: have a look at this :::: http://swati-ios.blogspot.in/2012/05/lazy-loading-of-images-in-table-ios-50.html

Comment: sure swati ill keep in touch with u there :)

Answer (score 1):

Append the string to currentnodecontent

```
if(!currentNodeContent ) 
    currentNodeContent = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
else
    [currentNodeContent appendString:string];
```

Comment: In Parser foundcharecter method

Comment: i had added the above code in `foundCharacters:` of my parsing section but it terminated the app by showing, Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to mutate immutable object with appendString:'
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: make this change in .h file NSMutableString *currentNodeContent;

Comment: remove this line and check . currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

Comment: if i remove it shows *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
and when i check the NSLog output it shows all images retrieved as null